# How to check logs in google workspace?

Tags: gmail, g-suite

I have google workspace account which has 24 users in a single domain, I want to check logs of a particular user. I followed this blog post but it has limited informations. Can anyone guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this by login to the admin console then “Reporting” then “Email Log Search”. There you can input email address which you want to track. It will details.